# How did PHP 5.3 break your application?

Tags: php

PHP 5.3 has been released some time ago and the developers tried to keep the number of backwards compatibility breaks low. What issues did you find while testing/migrating your code with PHP 5.3?

Comment: Why should this be CW? It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Because there's certainly no "right answer" - instead, there'll be lots of different answers.

Comment: imo the question is too broad to have a right answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about you, but I found all of these things I had to fix. :P

[Migrating from PHP 5.2.x to PHP 5.3.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php)

Comment: I added all stuff I knew there, but I was looking for community feedback in order to improve that page :-)

Comment: I was partially poking fun, but the answer is relevant to others as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using CakePHP 1.2 it causes a lot of deprecated notices in debug mode.
Upgrading to latest CakePHP version fix it.

Beside the deprecated notices, I did not find any major issue.